# Fallout Shelter: Weapon types, do they matter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Two questions:

1. Simply put, do different weapon types have different advantages / disadvantages to them, or is Damage the only thing that matters?

e.g. Does the Fat Man have high damage but low crit chance, Do Institute pistols have high crit but lower damage?

2. Depending on the answer to (1), is there such a thing as the best weapon combination for 3-man questing? Or is it just a matter of bunching up guns with the highest Damage?

e.g. One Fat-Man type, One Flamer and One pistol / fast gun.

Comment: Just to clarify, flamers don't do damage/time.

Comment: Yup. figured that out looking at combat. The only two unique attributes I've noted are that (a) Fat-Man types damage everyone in the room and (b) dwellers using institute pistols jump around when shooting (don't know if that has any advantages)

Comment: How long it takes to do damage per an amount of time with each gun might be a factor.

Comment: @Guy you mean the time between shots, and how much damage each shot does?

Comment: @Madhu don't quote me on this, but I believe the movement of the Dwellers is based on their Agility stat. I have a group I often send out on quests and regardless of the weapon they carry, they do move around 2-3 times per encounter. All of them have maxed out stats as well, so it might be something to test out

Answer (score 3):

From [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/4d5eu5/list_of_weapons/), based on the organized list of weapons, it seems that, *in general*, Heavy weapons will do the most damage, followed by Energy weapons.

It doesn't seem like the weapons are classed by type due to statistics, so much as they are classed based on what they actually are. A Heavy weapon and a Pistol that do the same damage should be equally effective when used by a single Vault dweller.

As to your question about stats across gun types, critical chance is determined by a Vault Dweller's Perception, while raw damage is determined by their Strength. Shot speed is determined by Agility. Therefore, these stats rely on the stats of the Vault Dweller who is equipping it. The type of gun does not determine this. If anything, it would be specific to each gun.

Comment: There's no evidence that Dweller's Strength affects Weapon Damage in Quests Combat, and there are many evidence that it does not affect Vault Combat. Agility affects Quest Combat _only_, but according to all evidence and tests, no SPECIAL affects Vault Combat _at all_

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the stat of the person, how powerfully the weapon is used. There won't be a difference except in damage.

Answer (score 0):

What I've noticed is, melee weapons, the attack position needs to be next to the target, if these two positions are already used by another melee or pistol wielder it cannot attack. Melee weapons are best for solo dwellers. I think pistols start attacking sooner because they needn't jockey into position for range good for a vault door guard in a crowd of enemies. My favourite weapons are 'Virgils Rifle' and 'Gatling Laser' perhaps with an 'MIRV' on missions (Splash damage is divided across all enemies) A 6-8 dmg weapon, mathematically, is equivalent to a 7.